# I have annoying white space between iFrames - I have tried everything i can think of

Tags: html, css, iframe, whitespace, removing-whitespace

On my website I have whitespace between my two google doodle iframes and can't get rid of it. I basically want a space to be as large as the space between pacman and soccer, however it is way too large. The 
 tags aren't causing it and am not sure whether the problem is in css or html. Thanks in advance. Website is at: http://blogs.ggs.wa.edu.au/strive/ryan/iMemory/googledoodles.html

```
<html lang=en>
<div class="webcontainer">
    <div class="articles">
        <div class="heading">
            <head>
                <title> iMemory - Games </title>
                <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="images/apple-icon-57x57.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="images/apple-icon-60x60.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="images/apple-icon-72x72.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="images/apple-icon-76x76.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/apple-icon-114x114.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="images/apple-icon-120x120.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="images/apple-icon-144x144.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="images/apple-icon-152x152.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="images/apple-icon-180x180.png">
                <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="images/android-icon-192x192.png">
                <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="images/favicon-32x32.png">
                <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="images/favicon-96x96.png">
                <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/favicon-16x16.png">
                <link rel="manifest" href="images/manifest.json">
                <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
                <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/ms-icon-144x144.png">
                <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
                <meta name="description" content="Free Web App designed to organise and memorise content you input into your own account which you can 
                access anywhere and anytime"/>
                <meta name="keywords" content="Organise, Customize, Memorise"/>
                <meta name="author" content="Ryan Bradley"/>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css"/>
                <script src="//load.sumome.com/" data-sumo-site-id="159e737b29bca598fa43ac7c7405dc459eac8999f385fc0254a2ca7043489618" async="async">
                </script>
            </head>
        </div>
            <body>
                <div class="center">
                    <div class="topbar">
                    </div>
                    <div class="socialmedia">
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function newPopup(url) {
                            popupWindow = window.open(
                            url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
                            }
                        </script>
                        <a class="fb" href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://www.facebook.com/iMemoryWebApp');"><img src="images/Facebook_logo_sml.png"  
                            alt="https://www.facebook.com/iMemoryWebApp" title="Click here to visit our Facebook Page..."/></a>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function newPopup(url) {
                            popupWindow = window.open(
                            url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
                            }
                        </script>
                        <a class="g" href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://plus.google.com/117832833332750535434/posts');"><img src="images/gedit.png"  
                            alt="https://plus.google.com/117832833332750535434/posts" title="Click here to visit our Google Plus Page..."/></a>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function newPopup(url) {
                            popupWindow = window.open(
                            url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
                            }
                        </script>
                        <a class="twitter" href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://twitter.com/iMemoryWebApp');"><img src="images/twitteredit.png"  
                            alt="https://twitter.com/iMemoryWebApp" title="Click here to visit our Twitter Page..."/></a>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function newPopup(url) {
                            popupWindow = window.open(
                            url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
                            }
                        </script>
                        <a class="pinterest" href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://www.pinterest.com/iMemoryWebApp/');"><img src="images/pinterestedit.png"  
                            alt="https://www.pinterest.com/iMemoryWebApp/" title="Click here to visit our Pinterest Page..."/></a>
                    </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class="nav">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills2">
                                <li class="#"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li class="#"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                <li class="#"><a href="contact_us.html">Contact</a></li>
                                <li class="#"><a href="sign_up.html">Sign Up</a></li>
                                <li class="#"><a href="store.html">Store</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Games</a>
                                    <ul class="subnav">
                                        <li class="ready"><a href="googledoodles.html" onclick="return false;">Google Doodles</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="scratchgames.html">Scratch Games</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="yourgames.html">Your Games</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="JavaScript:newPopup('https://scratch.mit.edu/scratch2download/');">Download Scratch</a>
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            function newPopup(url) {
                                            popupWindow = window.open(
                                            url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=800,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
                                            }
                                            </script>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>   
                                </li>       
                                <li class="#"><a href="sign_in.html">Sign In</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                    <div class="main">
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div class="googledoodles">
                            <iframe class="pacman" src="https://www.google.com/logos/2010/pacman10-hp.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <iframe class="doodle" src="https://www.google.com/logos/2012/football-2012-hp.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            <iframe class="doodle" src="http://www.google.com/logos/2012/basketball-2012-hp.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div class= "footer">
                            <hr class="footerline"/>
                            <p class="italic">
                                &copy 2015, iMemory | All rights reserved <br/>
                                Created by Ryan Bradley <br/>
                                Special thanks to eTIP 2015, Jackie Hildebrand and Shane Crosby <br/>
                                <br/>
                            </p>
                            <!-- Start: ©2015 TraceMyIP.org Service Code (100902-07172015)- DO NOT MODIFY //-->
                            <div>
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.tracemyip.org/tracker/lgUrl.php?stlVar2=1301&amp;rgtype=4684NR-IPIB&amp;pidnVar2=32777&amp;prtVar2=6&amp;scvVar2=12">
                            </script><div style="line-height:0px;"><a href="http://www.tracemyip.org/"><img src="//log.tracemyip.org/tracker/script.gif" alt="track my ip" style="border:0px;">
                            </a></div><noscript><img src="//s3.tracemyip.org/tracker/1301/4684NR-IPIB/32777/6/12/ans/" alt="track my ip" style="border:0px;"></noscript></div>
                            <!-- End: TraceMyIP.org Service Code //-->
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </body>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.doodle {
position: relative;
height: 61%;
width: 83%;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.doodle:hover {
transform: scale(1.2) ;
}

.pacman {
position: relative;
height: 41%;
width: 65%;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.pacman:hover {
transform: scale(1.2) ;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with the height of your `.doodle` class and a lot of `<br>` tags. I changed:

```
.doodle {
position: relative;
height: 61%;
width: 83%;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

to

```
.doodle {
position: relative;
height: 225px;
width: 83%;
transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

and removed all of the `<br>` between your iframes and it fixed the issue you were experiencing.

Comment: Thanks Fester! That fixed the problem. I thought my the googledoodles were caught up in the wrong tag :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problems with height of middle doodle.
Set it to absolute value (like 240px) and it will look a little bit better.